# Div wider than browser without browser scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, browser

I'm working on a layout where the main content div will have a with of 970px. Behind this div, I want a div with dimensions 1200x600px (it will contain a flash object) positioned like so:

```
width:1200px;
height:600px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-600px;
```

The problem is when the browser is sized to a width smaller than 1200px it get the horizontal scroll bar. I can fix that by:

```
body {overflow-x:hidden;}
```

But I DO want it to have the horizontal scroll bar when it get sized to less than 970px in width.

Basically, I am trying to get the 1200px div to behave more like a css background image. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works without JavaScript:

```
<body style="margin:0">
<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:600px;overflow:hidden;min-width:970px;z-index:0;">
 <div style="position:absolute;width:1200px;height:600px;left:50%;margin-left:-600px;">
  --flash object--
 </div>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;z-index:100;">
 --main content--
</div>
</body>
```

UPDATE:Had to make changes to accommodate your absolute div positioning (the parent div has to be absolutely positioned as well)

Comment: That puts the boxes in the right place in two dimensions, but it puts the content behind the background.

Comment: @danorton use the CSS property z-index to set your main body on top. I'll update my above code.

Answer (score 2):

A solution is possible entirely with CSS. The key pieces are **position: fixed** and **z-index: -1**. The two DIVs in this example are siblings, but there are other possibilities. This solution works with the latest versions of Chrome, FireFox, Safari, Opera and MSIE.

This does not work with MSIE6, which doesn’t correctly implement the **z-index** style, but there is an MSIE6-compatible solution (which shows the scrollbar at 1200px) if you’re able to rearrange things and add a DIV wrapper.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html title="html">
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #content
    {
      background: #ffffe8;
      height: 500px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 970px;
    }
    #background
    {
      background: #ffe8e8;
      height: 600px;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -600px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 1200px;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body title="body">
    <div id="content" title="#content">
      <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="background" title="#background">
      <p>background</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the onresize event and when its less than 970px, change overflow-x to auto or scroll.

if you are using jQuery, look up the [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) method

Comment: If you are going to do this, make sure you use dobouncing: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/examples/debouncing/  (Check the 2nd example)

Comment: debouncing looks very useful, That guy Ben Alman has written some neat plugins. I've recently used his haschange and BBQ plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CSS3 media query.

```
body{overflow:hidden;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 970px) {
     body{overflow:visible;}
}
```

First set the overflow on the body to be hidden so that it does not scroll. Then when the screen is less than 970px, set it back to visible so that it will scroll.