# How to give infinite width to a div?

Tags: html, css, width

Suppose there are two divs, A & B.

Div B has been given a width of 900px;

Screen resolution is 500px;

this would cause a horizontal scroll.

the problem is when I scroll to right, I see that DivA is not REALLY 100%.

Is there any ways I can make DivA always fill remaining space ?

see the image,

[image]

adding the following image for the purpose of explaining the problem :

[image]

Comment: can you show us your html or create a demo for that

Comment: It would be difficult to comment without having a look at code

Comment: Follow something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643965/div-wider-than-browser-without-browser-scrolling

Comment: The problem is that your table element is overflowing outside of its parent container (usually because the parent container has a width specified).  Notice how the other elements in the same container are also not expanding all the way to the right?  Without the code, a suitable solution cannot be offered.

Comment: I have added code and preview also. I hope u understand the problem.

I have tried float:left. but that dint make any difference.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jYMuY.png

Comment: I want divA to fill the space without knowing what is the width of divB....

Answer (score 0):

Hi now give to your `body min-width:900px;`

as like this

```
body{
min-width:900px;  // total width of your wraper as like wraper width 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you missing float: left of DivA

```
.DivA{
float: left
width: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the CSS3 -webkit-box-flex property it will help.
But the problem is, it wont work on all the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use `width:100%` for DivA It will fill the blank space. Moreover, add `float:left; position:relative` for both divs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: the div container is not expanding over the window width... the divA has autowidth, so it will expand to the container width, the grid div has a min-width greater than the window width (i think... can't see it in the code)

My answer is:

Html:

```
<h1>Child Expand Test</h1>
<form action="#">
    <div class="divContainer">
        <div class="divA">
            &nbsp;
        </div> 

        <div class="divGrid">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:
    form {
        /* just to show the form doesn't expand, if you need expand it */
        /* move the answer line to this class */
        background-color: silver;
        padding-top: 1em;
        padding-bottom: 1em;
    }

```
.divContainer {
    display: inline-block; /* this is the answer line, to expand over the window width */
}

.divA { /* this div will expand over the window width */
    background-color: red;
}

.divGrid {
    background-color: blue;
     min-width: 1500px; /* This is the reason why its needed, yo expand one child width over the size of the window */
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bjb7drdm/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }

    .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
    }

    .divA {
      background-color: lightblue;
      /* Optional styling for divA */
    }

    .divB {
      width: 900px;
      background-color: lightcoral;
      /* Optional styling for divB */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="divA">
  A
  </div>
  <div class="divB">
   B
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

you can make Div A always fill the remaining space by using CSS Flexbox or CSS Grid, which are both layout models in CSS that can help you achieve flexible and responsive designs. Here's an example using Flexbox:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .divA {
      flex: 1;
      background-color: lightblue;
      /* Optional styling for divA */
    }

    .divB {
      width: 900px;
      background-color: lightcoral;
      /* Optional styling for divB */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="divA">
    <!-- Content of Div A -->
  </div>
  <div class="divB">
    <!-- Content of Div B -->
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```